# Accessing and refreshing AngularJS ng-repeat inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am creating an application with AngularJS where there is a list of notices and users can comment on those notices.  However I am unsure on how to implement this commenting feature.  So far I have the following:

HTML:

> ```
> <div ng-repeat="notice in notices">
>     <!-- details about notice -->
>
>     <div ng-repeat="comment in notice.comments">
>        <p>{{comment.user}} - {{comment.text}}</p>
>
>        <form ng-submit="addComment()">
>             <input type="text" ng-model="newComment.user">
>             <textarea ng-model="newComment.text"></textarea>
>             <input type="submit" value="Add comment" />
>        </form>
>
>     </div>
>
> </div>
> ```

So in essense I am looping over notices and then inside the loop, looping over the comments.  I also have a form for adding new comments and here's where it get dicey for me.

`AddComment()` would take the new comment values, add it to the existing array of objects and also updates the database via factory.  However although the new values do appear in the notice.comments array I am unsure on how to update the comment list to show the newly added comment.

> How could I monitor the state of the objects inside the second ng-repeat to
>   accomodate for the changes presented by the form submit?  With a directive?

Comment: Normally I would update back in the controller, something like `$scope.notices[someIndex].comments.push(newComment)`

Comment: I posted a quick answer, happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to update the `notice.comments` array inside the controller on submit:

```
$scope.addComment = function() {
    //update your DB, yada yada yada
    //Update $scope.notices
    $scope.notices[someIndex].comments.push(newComment)
}
```